# Routing.generate() module (FriendsofSymfony/FOSjsRouting Bundle)

Tags: angularjs, json, symfony

I am trying to create a multiple input tags-input field in AngularJS, where I also want to add auto complete, so that on typing atleast 3 letters in the input field, the already existing tag names in the database appear as suggestions in the dropdown.

Here is the problem: 
I am using Routing.generate() module of the FOSjsRouting Bundle to call the controller action inside the javascript code (the action in-turn returns the following JsonResponse object):
[image]

Here is the controller code:

```
/**
 * @Route("/jsondata", options={"expose"=true}, name="my_route_to_json_data")
 */
public function tagsAction(Request $request)
{        
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
       'SELECT t.text
       FROM AppBundle:Tag t
       WHERE t.id > :id
       ORDER BY t.id ASC'
       )->setParameter('id', '0');

    $tagsdata = $query->getScalarResult();
    $response = new Response(json_encode($tagsdata));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;
}
```

Here is the AngularJS code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngTagsInput']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.loadTags = function(query) {
  return $http.get(Routing.generate('my_route_to_json_data'));
    };
  });
```

Here is the result I get:
[image]

Now when I save the Json response in `tags.json` and call it without using Routing.generate() module:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngTagsInput']);

            app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
               $scope.loadTags = function(query) {
               return $http.get('http://localhost/AngularTags/web/js/tags.json');

                }
            });
```

I get the perfectly working result:
[image]

Now I know the problem lies with proper usage of Routing.generate(). Since I am new to AngularJS and am just learning how to debug in console(which m loving by the way), m not entirely sure if I can figure out the problem on my own. Any help is appreciated.

n m sorry the post became too long, just wanted to make it clear.
So, awaiting response...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem with AngularJS, this is a problem of variable scope in JavaScript.

Did you import the scripts in your HTML [as specified in the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html)?

Comment: Thanks a tonn! I was missing out on router.js . It works fine now